# Delete list of words based on another list of words

Tags: notepad++

I have a long list of keywords, in a separate document, I have another long list of keywords that are acceptable. I need a way to delete everything on the list that does not appear in the second list, preferably in Notepad++.

Comment: This would not be easy to do from Notepad++, I think.  What other tools do you have available?

Comment: `grep -f` or `grep -vf` is the easy way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in many ways. For example, you could simply use a python script or execute a Linux command. Since you are using Notepad++, I'm assuming you are a Windows user. In that case, I would simply recommend downloading [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/download.html) or [Git](https://git-scm.com/downloads). This will allow you to execute a Linux command in Windows. You probably can do it in Notepad++ using diff option but keep in mind that Notepad++ might not be a good choice to perform this operation, especially for large files.

Let's say you have `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` and you want to get all keywords from `file1` if they are in `file2`.

file1.txt contains:

```
test
one
summer
and
spring
```

file2.txt contains:

```
summer
spring
winter
```

Once you download any of the applications mentioned above, you can execute the following command:

```
grep -f file1.txt file2.txt
grep -f file1.txt file2.txt > result.txt # to save the result in a file
```

result

```
summer
spring
```

If you want the inverted result then use `-v` option.

```
grep -vf file1.txt file2.txt
# output
winter
```

Also, to get all non keywords from file1 that are not in file2 then run this command:

```
grep -vf file2.txt file1.txt
# output
test
one
and
```